# Installing IBM PC DOS 4.0 on VMWare

Tags: vmware, disk-operating-system

I'm trying to install IBM PC DOS 4.0 onto a VMWare virtual machine.  The machine keeps rebooting, gets to a blank cursor, then reboots again.

I've booted a Windows 98 boot disk just fine so it's not the drive.  I then fdisked the drive, so I know it's not a partition problem

I got the installation disks today from a brand new, sealed box so I don't think there's anything wrong with the disks

Is there some sort of setting that I need to change in the BIOS that enables me to boot a PC DOS 4.0 installation disk?

I'm trying to get PC DOS 4.0 installed as a prerequisite for Windows 3.0.  I work for an IP law firm that needs a version of Office running on a system that's running similar to how it would be running prior to 1991 for prior art.  I'm not sure if FreeDOS would work for something like this

Comment: _Which_ DOS 4.0?  PC-DOS 4?  MS-DOS 4?  Concurrent DOS 4?  One of the OEM-branded versions of MS-DOS 4 that one could get, such as Compaq DOS 4 or Tandon DOS 4?  They're all different.  Name your operating system, and tag your question, _properly_.

Comment: sorry, it's IBM DOS 4.0

Comment: @Dennis, why? Existing `[dos]` tag is perfect. `Disk Operating System` is OS which System/360 ran.

Comment: @user539484: DOS is just an acronym for "Disk Operating System", and PC-DOS is part of the "Disk Operating System" family. The problem with `[dos]` is that DoS is an acronym for "denial-of-service", so [the DOS tag is ambiguous](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4969/the-dos-tag-is-ambiguous).

Comment: @Dennis, i dont think what DoS (network attack and more likely a serverfault subject) prevails over DOS (operating system and source of various suoeruser problems).

Answer (score 1):

There could be a problem with the disks, floppy disks can loose their magnetic charge over time.

As per your update here is my new recommended list of options in order of recommendation:

1. FreeDos [is compatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeDOS#Windows_1.0_to_3.xx) with windows versions 1.0 to 3.xx
2. Try [changing the configuration](https://superuser.com/a/367052/25625) of your VM.
3. DosBox [will run Windows 3.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcNkL.png) inside of it, it does not mention 3.0 so it may or may not work.
4. Try to find another copy of DOS.
5. Buy a disc recovery utility that works with floppies.

---

<s>Without more details of what your final goal is (are you just trying to play old DOS games or is there a specific reason you need DOS 4.0?) these are some generic suggestions.</s>

1. Use a DOS emulator if it suites your needs, [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) is very compatible with lots of software, you can even run windows 3.1 (and I think even 98 but I have never tested it) inside of it.
2. Use a DOS compatible alternative like [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/) if it suits your needs (again without details of what you are trying to do I don't know if this will be helpful)
3. Try to find [another set](http://www.ebay.com/sch/DOS-/11685/i.html?_catref=1&_dmpt=US_Software&_trksid=p3286.c0.m1538) of DOS disks.
4. If you already own it, as I would not recommend spending this much money to get DOS working, [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) works on floppy disks too, quite well in fact. I brought old floppy disk games back from the dead after using it.

If you post more details in your original question I may be able to give you more suggestions or tell you which of the existing suggestion will work best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you create the VM that:

- the hard disk is under 8GBytes (should really be under 2Gbytes - DOS does not recognize partitions past 2Gbytes)
- remove all virtual USB controllers, sound cards, and SCSI devices.
- make sure the first hard disk is connected via a virtual IDE adapter.
- make sure the CD ROM is connected via a virtual IDE adapter.
- no more than a combination of 4 virtual hard drives/CD-ROMs.
- no more than 2 virtual floppies.
- the RAM is set at something low like 16MB or 32MB.
- no network adapters.
- no printers.
- no more than 4 virtual serial ports and 3 virtual paralell ports.

I'd simplify it as much as possible during initial install and create 2Gbyte virtual IDE hard disk, an IDE CD-ROM, 16MB of RAM, and nothing else.  You can add other stuff later.

This would create as close to a DOS-era machine as possible.

Even if your disks are pristine, if they are floppies, the trouble might be with your 10-20 year old drive.

I don't know how well VMWare's BIOS performs the legacy BIOS functions that DOS relies on to function.  You may have better luck with a true "x86 emulator" rather than virtualization platform, such as Bochs or QEMU.